# IIS 7 Url Shortenr

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Before we get started, I know about URL Rewriting and Redirection, but this isnt really what I am looking for.

Is there an application or extension for IIS7 that will allow for URL shortening like [This one right here](http://is.gd/)?

I have seen a PHP version [Right about here](http://www.404techsupport.com/2010/06/host-your-own-url-shortener-with-shorty-yourls-or-others/), but I dont think that would be a readily reliable solution.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

PS: I am asking this before having to create my own..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these:

- [Shrinkr](http://shrinkr.codeplex.com/) - an Url Shortening Service which demonstrates some of
  the best practices in developing real life web applications
- [Jobping
  Url Shortener](http://jpurlshortener.codeplex.com/) - fully functioning 'bare bones' url shortening
  website

Answer (score 0):

Check this one on [sourceforge.net](http://shorturl-dotnet.sourceforge.net/), its not exactly the same but home it will be working for you...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I had taken a look at that project, but the last modification was over in 2009... I doubt it will be all-too-effective